# 'missing docstring' error, even though I have added them

Tags: python

```
def cat_latin_word(text):
    """converts the english into cat latin"""
    constant = "bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
    result = []
    for word in text.split():
        if word[0] in constant:
            word = (str(word)[1:] + str(word)[0] + "eeoow")
            result.append(word)
        elif word == "q":
            word = ("oodbyegeeoow")
            result.append(word)
        else:
            word = (str(word) + "meeoow")
            result.append(word)

    return ' '.join(result)

def cat_latin_from_sentence(text):
    """call the sub cat latin word sub function"""
    return cat_latin_word(text)

def main():
    """Calling for the main function"""
    text = input("Enter the english sentence: ")
    print("cat latin =" + " "+ cat_latin_from_sentence(text))
```

Comment: use a different question to ask something else. Don't edit your question to make it unrecognizable.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because it invalidated the posted answer. If the answer fixed your problem, you should mark it as 'accepted'. If you have a different question, ask another question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having to guess a bit here without you posting the actual `Pylint` message, but is it perhaps complaining that you're specifically missing a [*module* docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557110/what-to-put-in-a-python-module-docstring)? That is, a `docstring` at the top of the file describing what the whole module is for, rather than the function-level `docstrings` that you have shown.

Comment: 1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
Sorry, but your code doesn't pass the pylint style checks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20827387)